# OpenFileMapping always produces error 5 (FILE_ACCESS_DENIED)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, exe, reverse-engineering

I am sharing memory between two processes and a windows kernel driver.

Process A successfully creates the section object using `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE` protection as shown below:

```
    auto hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(
            INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, 
            NULL,     
            PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,
            0,                
            real_virtual_size,
            section_name
        );
```

Next, the kernel driver successfully creates a handle to the section object (with read, write, and execute access), as shown below:

```
status = ZwOpenSection(&section_handle , FILE_SHARE_READ, &attrs);

status = ZwMapViewOfSection(section_handle, NtCurrentProcess(), &mapped_base, 0,
                map_size, NULL, &map_size, ViewShare, 0, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE | PAGE_NOCACHE);
```

My problem occurs when Process B attempts to open a handle with read/write access to this shared memory section.

```
       auto handle = OpenFileMapping(
                       FILE_MAP_WRITE | FILE_MAP_READ,  
                       FALSE,          
                       section_name
    );
```

In process B, `OpenFileMapping` causes `GetLastError` to return 5 (`FILE_ACCESS_DENIED`). `OpenFileMapping` only succeeds if I pass `FILE_MAP_READ` protection by itself, but I'm trying to obtain both read and write access to the section.

Comment: ZwMapViewOfSection `[in] Win32Protect`

Specifies the type of protection for the region of initially committed pages. Device and intermediate drivers should set this value to `PAGE_READWRITE`. Nothing is about `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE | PAGE_NOCACHE`.

Comment: `ZwOpenSection()` is opening the section for read-only access, but then `ZwMapViewOfSection()` is mapping a view of that section for read/write access.

Comment: are process B have not the same token as process A ? this is less privileged process ? kernel path here unrelated at all. only A create object with defaulr security descriptor and B can not open it

Comment: @RbMm Process B is not launched as admin while Process A is launched as administrator. Is there a way to make the section object in process A accessible non privileged processes?

Comment: of course. you need set appropriate security descriptor on object. for instance such- `{ SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION, 0, SE_DACL_PRESENT }`. all what you write about driver unrelated to question. from another side you forget say that name of section begin with `"Global\\"`